# Link to a local php file in xampp/Apache?

Tags: php, apache, xampp

In my php script how do I link to another file? What should the address be? 
If it was on a hosted server it would be simple. Eg

```
Echo File_get_contents ('foldername/test.php');
```

test.php is in the default folder

I tried http://localhost/test.php

Comment: What would it look like as a whole?

Comment: C drive, xampp, htdocs is the full address for the folder but I can't seem to get it to work in the script.

Comment: The folder name is actually "htdocs"

Comment: When you use xampp, htdocs is the location where you keep your PHP application. e.g, if you were using Drupal you would download and extract it to htdocs... But, Apache can be configured to map urls to specific folders inside your php app, so that you may be able to set up multi-site with a single php app.e.g in drupal i can map http://localhost/ to htdocs/drupal/sites/default. and at the same time have http://localhost2 map to htdocs/drupal/sites/default2. It depends on the configuration. Use getcwd() to get your current working directory and then work your way just like you have been trying.

Comment: Ok. I tried getcwd() and it gave me the address from the C drive but this didn't work when I used it in the file get contents line.

Comment: I will try to simplify. When my first script redirects to another script in the same folder it does so no problem. But in the second script when I want to use File get contents it doesn't find the linked file. For example the file needed is called filename.htm but when I use file_get_contents('filename.htm'); it doesn't find the file. ?

Comment: As it is in the SAME folder as the script it's embedded in the. I shouldn't need a long file path before the name should I ? Even if I did, I have tried to add the absolute path but am having trouble getting it correct.

Comment: could you please tell what is the location of the two files that you are trying to access w.r.t. c drive? also what is returned when you use getcwd();inside the script where you are using file_get_contents($url);?

Answer (score 0):

My fault.

I saved the filename as

Filename.htm

And so the actual file name was

Filename.htm.htm

Which I didn't realise until I clicked on properties. 
The path in php code was simply

filename.htm